# How to use VBA for web parsing table with data-reactid

Tags: html, vba, reactjs, parsing

I am trying to parse each element from a table from a website, however, the table is a reference with data-reactid, the question is how to use .Document.getElementsByXXX to parse each element?

```
'VBA to Get Table Data

    tblNameArr = Array(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 4), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 4), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 4), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 4))
    tblStartRow = 6
    Set elemCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    For t = 0 To elemCollection.Length - 1
        For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r + tblStartRow, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r

        ActiveSheet.Cells(r + tblStartRow + 2, 1) = tblNameArr(t)
        tblStartRow = tblStartRow + r + 4

    Next t
```

[image: Below is the source code of the web which I need to parse]

The link for the website which I need to parse:

http://gu.qq.com/hk00001/gp/income

Comment: do web search for "getelementsby"

Comment: It looks like the class name for the table is "fin-table", and it's the only table on that page with that class name.  So you can refer to the table using `IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("fin-table")(0)`.

Comment: @Domenic, your answer works as a charm! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS selector of `.fin-table`. The "." means className. It is applied via the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of `document`.

```
IE.Document.querySelector(".fin-table")
```

It returns a single node which is ok as this is the first/only with that className.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class name for the table is `"fin-table"`, and it's the only table on that page with that class name. So you can refer to the table using:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("fin-table")(0)
```

<sub>Answer by @Domonic replicated from comments to here</sub>

Comment: @Dominic I have replicated your comment here. If you wish to potentially gain rep then leave a comment here, post an answer, and I will delete this.